# How can i render a component by a for loop?

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of components, so I want to print the content. My attempt is like this:

```
const fields = [<Invites />]

return (
    <Card style={{ width: 600 }}>
        {fields.map((Item, index) => <Item />)}
    </Card>
)
```

But, I got this error:

> react-dom.development.js:28439 Uncaught Error: Element type is
> invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a
> class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

BTW, this is the `<Invites />` component:

```
const Invites = () => {
    return (
        <Form.Item className='form-item item-container' label="Invites">
            <span>
                <Input />
            </span>
        </Form.Item>
    )
}
```

Comment: As error suggest you should rename item to Item. There is a convention when you name your components. It should start with capital letter.

Comment: OP I really hope the closing tag for <Card> is missing because you forgot to paste it...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to change your code to this:

```
{fields.map((item, index) => item)}
```

Comment: but i am getting this error now react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Comment: You have to add a key prop. One way to do it is to wrap item in a view like this: <View key={index}>{item}</View>

Answer (score 1):

Since each item in `fields` is already an element, you don't need to do anything at all:

```
const fields = [<Invites />];

return (
    <Card
        style={{ width: 600 }}
    >
        {fields}
    </Card>
);
```

React will always do its best to render arrays, and in the case of an array of elements, it renders them all for you.

---

To add keys you can also use `React.Fragment`:

```
return (
    <Card
        style={{ width: 600 }}
    >
        {fields.map((item, index) => <React.Fragment key={index}>{item}</React.Fragment>)}
    </Card>
);
```

Comment: but i am getting this error now react-jsx-dev-runtime.development.js:87 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Comment: @letters Edited answer with a way to add the key prop.